# How do you set all of your Sinatra responses to be JSON?

Tags: json, sinatra

I've been able to set all of my content types to be JSON in a `before` block, but is there a sinatra after filter that allows me to run to_json on all of the responses (instead of writing `to_json` 3 times in my example below)?

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

before do
  content_type :json
end

get '/' do
  { song: "Hello" }.to_json
end

get '/go' do
  { song: "Go Yo Ho" }.to_json
end

get '/hi' do
  { song: "Wake me Up" }.to_json
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that in an `after` block:

```
before do
  content_type :json
end

get '/' do
  { a: 1 }
end

after do
  response.body = JSON.dump(response.body)
end
```

Sinatra will re-calculate the correct content length for the updated body value.

An alternate way would be to use a helper:

```
helper do
  def j(data)
    JSON.dump(data)
  end
end

get '/' do
  j({ a: 1 })
end
```

The [`Sinatra::JSON`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/json.html) project does the same thing. Also, you might want to look at libraries designed for building APIs like [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) or [Goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath). These two libraries provide a easy way to attach decoders and encoders to handle this type of automatic conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Put `set :default_content_type, 'application/json'` and all your responses will include a `Content-Type: application/json` header.